# Flutter husky package for creating git hooks

Tags: bash, git, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages

I already have a pre-commit hook in my project, but I want to force all people in my project to use it. For that purpose, I want to write a flutter library for creating files in a flutter project directory(like a husky in js world)! All that I have searched are about widgets libraries and so on!

I know that in js libraries in package.json there is a script object with install property. In this property, anybody can write to run a script. Is there an opportunity to do the same thing in dart or flutter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply Git hooks in Flutter projects using Lefthook. I've written about it [here](https://dev.to/arthurdenner/git-hooks-in-flutter-projects-with-lefthook-52n). However, a pre-commit hook can be bypassed with the --no-verify flag, so I'd suggest you to also integrate checks on a pipeline. I've written about this using [GitHub Actions](https://dev.to/arthurdenner/run-checks-for-flutter-projects-with-github-actions-7ld) and [GitLab CI](https://dev.to/arthurdenner/run-checks-for-flutter-projects-with-gitlab-ci-1i42) in case you're using one of these services.